# How to detect state of GIF

Tags: c#, winforms

As the title says I have a `PictureBox` with a GIF image.

Let's say that it consists 5 images. How can I detect the current image being displayed ? I've tried achieving this effect using array of images and iterating through it using a timer however it doesn't look well at all, so I'm looking for different solution.

Comment: I know you can specify what frame you want to display, and get a list of all frames, but I don't think you can determine which frame is actually being displayed. You could break the gif into its individual frames and display each one in sequence. Doing it that way would allow you to determine the frame by tracking it yourself. If you want to do that, I can provide an answer with a small example.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I've already tried that but if that the only way I would still like to see your implementation, I might have done it wrong..

Comment: The GIF inside the PictureBox is animated by a private ImageAnimator object that PictureBox uses.  It is private.  PictureBox is not exactly rocket science, you can easily create your own by deriving from Control and taking a peek at the Reference Source to know what to do.  So you have your own ImageAnimator.

Comment: Exactly, you could implement your own `PictureBox` control as an `AnimatedPictureBox` that contains your own code that iterates through a list of frames from the gif and provides a public set of properties that get/set the current frame, the speed of the frame swap, etc...

Comment: How come it's unclear what I'm asking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a simple way to determine your current frame unfortunately.

Likely, from what you said in your question, you probably have a solution similar to this. It isn't pretty, but it should basically give you access to determine what frame you are currently displaying.

This may need a little debugging, but it is just a quick mock-up. It should mostly work though, but may throw a thread or object reference exception when you exit the form with the image playing:

```
public partial class frmGifPlayer : Form
{
    List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
    int imageIdx = 0;
    bool playing = false;
    public frmGifPlayer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLoadGIF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (file.ShowDialog(this) != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }
        Image img = Image.FromFile(file.FileName);

        lock (images)
        {
            // Load your images into a List<Image> collection...
            images.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < img.GetFrameCount(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Time); i++)
            {
                img.SelectActiveFrame(System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension.Time, i);
                images.Add(new Bitmap(img));
            }
        }


    }

    private void PlayImages(List<Image> images)
    {
        // Cycle through the images in a thread...
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) =>
            {
                List<Image> img = (List<Image>)o;
                int curIdx = 0;
                do
                {
                    lock (images)
                    {
                        // Update your variables then callback to the form to change the image.
                        imageIdx = curIdx;
                        pbGif.Image = img[imageIdx];
                        Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            txtCurFrame.Text = imageIdx.ToString();
                        }));
                        curIdx++;
                        if (curIdx >= img.Count)
                            curIdx = 0;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5));
                } while (playing);
            }), images);
    }


    private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (images)
        {
            playing = !playing;
        }
        if (playing)
        {
            btnStartStop.Text = "Stop";
            PlayImages(images);
        }
        else
            btnStartStop.Text = "Start";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer exactly what i wanted, just one question how can i release the locked `images` or abort the thread that is running there ?

Comment: Well, since the thread is started as a background worker, once `playing` is set to `false` the loop in the thread will break and return. The thread will dispose itself. So just set the variable to false and let it end itself.

Comment: I currently have the `lock` statement wrapped in a `try/catch` block because sometimes if i press the button too fast it will throw exception that the object is being used somewhere else  in which case i `return`. Is there any better solution to this ?